# Retrieve all user profiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, user-profile

I'm in struggle to retrieving all user profiles in a single request. Is it possible to retrieve all user profiles including properties with REST search API?

Answer (score 2):

Did not find any REST API which can find all users' profile in a single request.

But we can search in the *User Profile* using **REST API**. Following is the end-point of searching user's profile including properties.

```
"/_api/search/query?querytext='whatToSearch'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&rowlimit='100'&selectproperties='PictureURL, PreferredName, Country'"
```

Another thing we can find all site users by following **APIs**

```
_api/web/siteusers
```

*OR*

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/get-user-profile-properties-from-sharepoint-online-using-csom-console-application/

```
Get User Collection
 UserCollection users = tenantContext.Web.SiteUsers;
                tenantContext.Load(users);
                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Get Personal Propertie of user

> ```
>  PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(tenantContext);
> PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();
>  tenantContext.Load(personProperties);
>                 tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>
>
>
>   string[] userProfileProperties = new string[personProperties.UserProfileProperties.Count+1];
>
>         // string[] userProfileProperties = { "AccountName", "FirstName", "LastName", "PreferredName", "Manager", "AboutMe",
> ```
>
> "PersonalSpace", "PictureURL", "UserName", "WorkEmail", "SPS-Birthday"
>   };
>               int i = 0;
>               foreach (string key in personProperties.UserProfileProperties.Keys)
>               {
>
> ```
>             userProfileProperties[i] = key;
>             i++;
>         }
>
>
>         foreach (string propertyKey in userProfileProperties)
>         {
>             items.Append(propertyKey);
>             items.Append(",");
>         }
>         items.AppendLine();
>
> foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User user in users)
>                 {
>                     try
>                     {
>                         if (user.PrincipalType != Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User) continue;
>
>                         UserProfilePropertiesForUser userProfilePropertiesForUser = new
> ```
>
> UserProfilePropertiesForUser(tenantContext, user.LoginName,
>   userProfileProperties);
>                               IEnumerable profileProperties = peopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
>                               tenantContext.Load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
>                               tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
>                               foreach (string property in profileProperties)
>                               {
>                                   items.Append(property);
>                                   items.Append(",");
>                               }
>                               items.AppendLine();
>                           }
>                           catch (Exception ex)
>                           {
>                               throw ex;
>                           }
>
> ```
>                 }
> ```

you will get all user Properties with username

Thanks